# terraform, foreach and a module - wait after action on one of element from the list

Tags: terraform, terraform-modules

Terraform is not waiting for the full module creation within foreach. Instead of finishing entire module creation in one iteration it is creating first resource from the module for every list element, then iterates over the list and creates second module, and so on.

Also I use parallelism=1 option when running the apply: `terraform apply -parallelism=1`

```
#templates/iam.tf
variable "project_id2" {}
variable "project_id" {}
variable "user" {}
variable "role" {}

resource "google_project_iam_member" "first_me" {
  project = var.project_id2
  role    = var.role
  member  = "user:${var.user}"
}

resource "google_project_iam_member" "then_me" {
  project = var.project_id
  role    = var.role
  member  = "user:${var.user}"
  depends_on = [
    google_project_iam_member.first_me
  ]
}

resource "time_sleep" "wait_seconds" {
  create_duration = "11s"

  depends_on = [google_project_iam_member.then_me]
}

resource "null_resource" "sleep_after_project_import" {
  depends_on = [
    time_sleep.wait_seconds,
    google_project_iam_member.then_me
  ]
}

# ---

# ./main.tf 
locals {
  roles_for_bindings = [
    "roles/accessapproval.invalidator",
    "roles/actions.Viewer",
    "roles/serviceconsumermanagement.tenancyUnitsAdmin",
  ]
}

module "role_binding_sleep_test" {
  source     = "./templates/iam"
  for_each   = toset(local.test)
  project_id = "some_project_id"
  project_id2 = "some_project_id2"
  role       = each.key
  user       = "test@test.com"
}
```

### Logs

```
module.role_binding_sleep_test["roles/accessapproval.invalidator"].google_project_iam_member.first_me: Creation complete after 9s [id=some_project_id2/roles/accessapproval.invalidator/user:test@test.com]
module.role_binding_sleep_test["roles/actions.Viewer"].google_project_iam_member.first_me: Creating...
module.role_binding_sleep_test["roles/actions.Viewer"].google_project_iam_member.first_me: Creation complete after 9s [id=some_project_id2/roles/actions.Viewer/user:test@test.com]
module.role_binding_sleep_test["roles/serviceconsumermanagement.tenancyUnitsAdmin"].google_project_iam_member.first_me: Creating...
module.role_binding_sleep_test["roles/serviceconsumermanagement.tenancyUnitsAdmin"].google_project_iam_member.first_me: Creation complete after 9s [id=some_project_id2/roles/serviceconsumermanagement.tenancyUnitsAdmin/user:test@test.com]
module.role_binding_sleep_test["roles/accessapproval.invalidator"].google_project_iam_member.then_me: Creating...
module.role_binding_sleep_test["roles/accessapproval.invalidator"].google_project_iam_member.then_me: Creation complete after 9s [id=some_project_id1/roles/accessapproval.invalidator/user:test@test.com]
module.role_binding_sleep_test["roles/actions.Viewer"].google_project_iam_member.then_me: Creating...
module.role_binding_sleep_test["roles/actions.Viewer"].google_project_iam_member.then_me: Creation complete after 9s [id=some_project_id1/roles/actions.Viewer/user:test@test.com]
module.role_binding_sleep_test["roles/serviceconsumermanagement.tenancyUnitsAdmin"].google_project_iam_member.then_me: Creating...
module.role_binding_sleep_test["roles/serviceconsumermanagement.tenancyUnitsAdmin"].google_project_iam_member.then_me: Creation complete after 10s [id=some_project_id1/roles/serviceconsumermanagement.tenancyUnitsAdmin/user:test@test.com]
module.role_binding_sleep_test["roles/accessapproval.invalidator"].time_sleep.wait_seconds: Creating...
module.role_binding_sleep_test["roles/accessapproval.invalidator"].time_sleep.wait_seconds: Still creating... [10s elapsed]
module.role_binding_sleep_test["roles/accessapproval.invalidator"].time_sleep.wait_seconds: Creation complete after 11s [id=2023-12-04T13:22:47Z]
module.role_binding_sleep_test["roles/actions.Viewer"].time_sleep.wait_seconds: Creating...
module.role_binding_sleep_test["roles/actions.Viewer"].time_sleep.wait_seconds: Still creating... [10s elapsed]
module.role_binding_sleep_test["roles/actions.Viewer"].time_sleep.wait_seconds: Creation complete after 11s [id=2023-12-04T13:22:59Z]
module.role_binding_sleep_test["roles/serviceconsumermanagement.tenancyUnitsAdmin"].time_sleep.wait_seconds: Creating...
module.role_binding_sleep_test["roles/serviceconsumermanagement.tenancyUnitsAdmin"].time_sleep.wait_seconds: Still creating... [10s elapsed]
module.role_binding_sleep_test["roles/serviceconsumermanagement.tenancyUnitsAdmin"].time_sleep.wait_seconds: Creation complete after 11s [id=2023-12-04T13:23:10Z]
module.role_binding_sleep_test["roles/actions.Viewer"].null_resource.sleep_after_project_import: Creating...
module.role_binding_sleep_test["roles/actions.Viewer"].null_resource.sleep_after_project_import: Creation complete after 0s [id=111111]
module.role_binding_sleep_test["roles/accessapproval.invalidator"].null_resource.sleep_after_project_import: Creating...
module.role_binding_sleep_test["roles/accessapproval.invalidator"].null_resource.sleep_after_project_import: Creation complete after 0s [id=111112]
module.role_binding_sleep_test["roles/serviceconsumermanagement.tenancyUnitsAdmin"].null_resource.sleep_after_project_import: Creating...
module.role_binding_sleep_test["roles/serviceconsumermanagement.tenancyUnitsAdmin"].null_resource.sleep_after_project_import: Creation complete after 0s [id=111113]
```

### Logs I was expecting:

```
module.role_binding_sleep_test["roles/accessapproval.invalidator"].google_project_iam_member.first_me: Creating...
module.role_binding_sleep_test["roles/accessapproval.invalidator"].google_project_iam_member.first_me: Creation complete after 9s [id=some_project_id2/roles/accessapproval.invalidator/user:test@test.com]
module.role_binding_sleep_test["roles/accessapproval.invalidator"].google_project_iam_member.then_me: Creating...
module.role_binding_sleep_test["roles/accessapproval.invalidator"].google_project_iam_member.then_me: Creation complete after 9s [id=some_project_id1/roles/accessapproval.invalidator/user:test@test.com]
module.role_binding_sleep_test["roles/accessapproval.invalidator"].time_sleep.wait_seconds: Creating...
module.role_binding_sleep_test["roles/accessapproval.invalidator"].time_sleep.wait_seconds: Still creating... [10s elapsed]
module.role_binding_sleep_test["roles/accessapproval.invalidator"].time_sleep.wait_seconds: Creation complete after 11s [id=2023-12-04T13:22:47Z]
module.role_binding_sleep_test["roles/accessapproval.invalidator"].null_resource.sleep_after_project_import: Creating...
module.role_binding_sleep_test["roles/accessapproval.invalidator"].null_resource.sleep_after_project_import: Creation complete after 0s [id=111111]
# now 1st foreach iteration for role should end and next start
module.role_binding_sleep_test["roles/serviceconsumermanagement.tenancyUnitsAdmin"].google_project_iam_member.first_me: Creating...
module.role_binding_sleep_test["roles/serviceconsumermanagement.tenancyUnitsAdmin"].google_project_iam_member.first_me: Creation complete after 9s [id=some_project_id2/roles/serviceconsumermanagement.tenancyUnitsAdmin/user:test@test.com]
module.role_binding_sleep_test["roles/serviceconsumermanagement.tenancyUnitsAdmin"].google_project_iam_member.then_me: Creating...
module.role_binding_sleep_test["roles/serviceconsumermanagement.tenancyUnitsAdmin"].google_project_iam_member.then_me: Creation complete after 10s [id=some_project_id1/roles/serviceconsumermanagement.tenancyUnitsAdmin/user:test@test.com]
module.role_binding_sleep_test["roles/serviceconsumermanagement.tenancyUnitsAdmin"].time_sleep.wait_seconds: Creating...
module.role_binding_sleep_test["roles/serviceconsumermanagement.tenancyUnitsAdmin"].time_sleep.wait_seconds: Still creating... [10s elapsed]
module.role_binding_sleep_test["roles/serviceconsumermanagement.tenancyUnitsAdmin"].time_sleep.wait_seconds: Creation complete after 11s [id=2023-12-04T13:23:10Z]
module.role_binding_sleep_test["roles/serviceconsumermanagement.tenancyUnitsAdmin"].null_resource.sleep_after_project_import: Creating...
module.role_binding_sleep_test["roles/serviceconsumermanagement.tenancyUnitsAdmin"].null_resource.sleep_after_project_import: Creation complete after 0s [id=111112]
# now 2nd foreach iteration for role should end and next start
module.role_binding_sleep_test["roles/actions.Viewer"].google_project_iam_member.then_me: Creating...
module.role_binding_sleep_test["roles/actions.Viewer"].google_project_iam_member.then_me: Creation complete after 9s [id=some_project_id1/roles/actions.Viewer/user:test@test.com]
module.role_binding_sleep_test["roles/actions.Viewer"].time_sleep.wait_seconds: Creating...
module.role_binding_sleep_test["roles/actions.Viewer"].time_sleep.wait_seconds: Still creating... [10s elapsed]
module.role_binding_sleep_test["roles/actions.Viewer"].time_sleep.wait_seconds: Creation complete after 11s [id=2023-12-04T13:22:59Z]
module.role_binding_sleep_test["roles/actions.Viewer"].null_resource.sleep_after_project_import: Creating...
module.role_binding_sleep_test["roles/actions.Viewer"].null_resource.sleep_after_project_import: Creation complete after 0s [id=111113]
```

Comment: Is this causing an actual problem? Or is it just not creating resources in the order you expected? Terraform doesn't iterate over a list of resources like you are describing.  Terraform looks at your .tf files and creates a graph of all resources to be created, and then determines the best order to create those resources. It would have iterated over your modules during the plan phase, not the apply phase.

Comment: yes, it's causing actual problem. I need to create one set of elements (resources declared in the module, and all connected with depends_on) and then wait few minutes for the propagation of the newly created resource (it's doing some actions under the hood for a few minutes). And there is hundreds of such groups on my list, so declaring of the modules would make this code a total mess. In any programming language when you loop with for/foreach over a list of the items, if there is no async methods there is assurance your code will run in selected order, all from the loop before next iteration.

Comment: "In any programming language when you loop with for/foreach over a list of the items, if there is no async methods there is assurance your code will run in selected order, all from the loop before next iteration" That may be true for any *imperative* programming language. Terraform is a declarative programming language.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `count` or `for_each` in Terraform, the meaning is to declare zero or more *independent* instances of the same module or resource. Terraform therefore assumes it can perform operations on those independent instances concurrently, or in any sequential order.

If your instances are not actually independent of one another -- that is, if any one of them must be acted on before another for the result to be correct -- then `for_each` is not a suitable tool to use. Instead, you'll need to declare multiple `module` blocks and explain the relationships between them by having the arguments in one block refer to the output values from the other.

Dependencies in Terraform are between configuration blocks, *not* the multiple instances that they can potentially declare. Any time you need to describe a dependency between two objects, they will need to be declared as two separate configuration blocks.

Comment: Those groups have no dependency, I just need to wait few minutes after one group gets created (under the hood propagation I have no control of) and then create new group (hundreds of them and about 5min break between each creation).

Comment: Don't you feel that the way I've declared the modules resources is logical and based on a programming languages behavior this should work as I've described? Get first element, create resources from the module and when you are done, take next element from the list. Now TF is taking first element, making first resource... taking second element, making first resource. Then iterate again over the list and create second resource.

Comment: It sounds like Terraform will not be a suitable tool to meet your goal. I think you should solve this problem using a different tool.